# Apache spark - how to monitor Kafka message delivery?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

Would like to monitor Kafka message delivery metrics - mostly how many messages were consumed or lost, latency, eventually consumer offsets and so on...

Found Apache Spark, but I don't really understand, if it can "plugged easily into Kafka" without writing any (java) code.

What I would appreciate is just to change configuration for Kafka connection in some configuration file, where to store message delivery metrics and display and query it in some UI.

Is there "more automated" way to use Spark-Kafka message delivery monitoring, than writing (java) applications from scratch ?
Are there some already finished applications, which can be used freely ?
How to set the chain Kafka - Spark - (database ?) - UI in the most easy and automated way ?
Can Spark monitor other metrics also - clusters, brokers, topics, insync replicas, number of partitions, ... and so on ?

Comment: Can you please share the link where you saw that apache-spark could be used for monitoring apache-kafka matrics?

Comment: Mostly from here:http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#monitoring-applications, but now, on the second read I see that receiver is not kafka consumer. My fault, but still, do you know if kafka message delivery can be monitored with no paid software ? Thanks

Comment: Are you interested in using beats with an ELK-stack?

Comment: I tried metric beat with both kafka and zookeeper modules, with all metricsets enabled, but there is only very limited number of metrics. I am more about to use JMXTrans. But since JMXTrans can provide metrics about processes separately, I need also to be able to monitor data delivery. Found Chaperone, do you have any experience with that ?

Comment: Well, I have some experience with beats and I knew they were limited. I just thought that you could used that for a start then improve later. Now regarding JMXTrans, sorry but I have no experience with that. I also found this project https://github.com/linkedin/kafka-monitor. You could try that if JMXTrans does not work.

Comment: It looks very promising, will try it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experiments with different software, kafka-monitor showed to fit best for my case.
It creates topic with partitions over whole cluster and provides metrics about production and consumption like message loss, duplication and end-to-end lag.

Start kafka-monitor like so:

```
cd <path_to_kafka_monitor>
export JMX_PORT=<some_port>
./bin/kafka-monitor-start.sh config/kafka-monitor.properties
```

Metrics are collected with jmxTrans. Query used:

```
{
    "servers": [{
        "port": "9999",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "queries": [{
                "obj": "kafka.consumer:type=consumer-coordinator-metrics,client-id=*",
                "attr": ["assigned-partitions","commit-latency-avg","commit-rate","heartbeat-rate","heartbeat-response-time-max",
                        "join-rate","join-time-avg","join-time-max","last-heartbeat-seconds-ago","sync-rate","sync-time-avg","sync-time-max"],
                "resultAlias": "monitor-consumer.consumer-coordinator-metrics;client-id",
                "outputWriters": [{
                    "@class": "com.googlecode.jmxtrans.model.output.InfluxDbWriterFactory",
                    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8086/",
                    "username": "root",
                    "password": "root",
                    "database": "monitor",
                    "typeNames": ["client-id"]
                }]
            },
            {
                "obj": "kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics,client-id=*",
                "attr": ["bytes-consumed-rate","fetch-latency-avg","fetch-latency-max","records-consumed-rate","records-lag-max",
                        "records-per-request-avg"],
                "resultAlias": "monitor-consumer.consumer-fetch-manager-metrics,client-id",
                "outputWriters": [{
                    "@class": "com.googlecode.jmxtrans.model.output.InfluxDbWriterFactory",
                    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8086/",
                    "username": "root",
                    "password": "root",
                    "database": "monitor",
                    "typeNames": ["client-id"]
                }]
            },
            {
                "obj": "kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics,client-id=*,topic=*",
                "attr": ["bytes-consumed-rate","fetch-size-avg","fetch-size-max","records-consumed-rate","records-per-request-avg"],
                "resultAlias": "monitor-consumer-fetch-manager-metrics;client-id,topic",
                "outputWriters": [{
                    "@class": "com.googlecode.jmxtrans.model.output.InfluxDbWriterFactory",
                    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8086/",
                    "username": "root",
                    "password": "root",
                    "database": "monitor",
                    "typeNames": ["client-id","topic"]
                }]
            },
            {
                "obj": "kafka.consumer:type=consumer-metrics,client-id=*",
                "attr": [],
                "resultAlias": "monitor-consumer-metrics;client-id",
                "outputWriters": [{
                    "@class": "com.googlecode.jmxtrans.model.output.InfluxDbWriterFactory",
                    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8086/",
                    "username": "root",
                    "password": "root",
                    "database": "monitor",
                    "typeNames": ["client-id"]
                }]
            },
            {
                "obj": "kafka.consumer:type=consumer-node-metrics,client-id=*,node-id=*",
                "attr": ["incoming-byte-rate","outgoing-byte-rate","request-latency-avg","request-rate","request-size-avg","response-rate"],
                "resultAlias": "monitor-consumer-node-metrics;client-id,node-id",
                "outputWriters": [{
                    "@class": "com.googlecode.jmxtrans.model.output.InfluxDbWriterFactory",
                    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8086/",
                    "username": "root",
                    "password": "root",
                    "database": "monitor",
                    "typeNames": ["client-id","node-id"]
                }]
            },
            {
                "obj": "kafka.producer:type=producer-metrics,client-id=*",
                "attr": [],
                "resultAlias": "monitor-producer-metrics;client-id",
                "outputWriters": [{
                    "@class": "com.googlecode.jmxtrans.model.output.InfluxDbWriterFactory",
                    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8086/",
                    "username": "root",
                    "password": "root",
                    "database": "monitor",
                    "typeNames": ["client-id"]
                }]
            },
            {
                "obj": "kafka.producer:type=producer-node-metrics,client-id=*,node-id=*",
                "attr": ["incoming-byte-rate","outgoing-byte-rate","request-latency-avg","request-rate","request-size-avg","response-rate"],
                "resultAlias": "monitor-producer-node-metrics;client-id,node-id",
                "outputWriters": [{
                    "@class": "com.googlecode.jmxtrans.model.output.InfluxDbWriterFactory",
                    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8086/",
                    "username": "root",
                    "password": "root",
                    "database": "monitor",
                    "typeNames": ["client-id","node-id"]
                }]
            },
            {
                "obj": "kafka.producer:type=producer-topic-metrics,client-id=*,topic=*",
                "attr": [],
                "resultAlias": "monitor-producer-topic-metrics;client-id,topic",
                "outputWriters": [{
                    "@class": "com.googlecode.jmxtrans.model.output.InfluxDbWriterFactory",
                    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8086/",
                    "username": "root",
                    "password": "root",
                    "database": "monitor",
                    "typeNames": ["client-id","topic"]
                }]
            },
            {
                "obj": "kmf.services:type=consume-service,name=single-cluster-monitor",
                "attr": [],
                "resultAlias": "monitor-consume-service.single-cluster-monitor",
                "outputWriters": [{
                    "@class": "com.googlecode.jmxtrans.model.output.InfluxDbWriterFactory",
                    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8086/",
                    "username": "root",
                    "password": "root",
                    "database": "monitor"
                }]
            },
            {
                "obj": "kmf.services:type=produce-service,name=single-cluster-monitor",
                "attr": [],
                "resultAlias": "monitor-produce-service.single-cluster-monitor",
                "outputWriters": [{
                    "@class": "com.googlecode.jmxtrans.model.output.InfluxDbWriterFactory",
                    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8086/",
                    "username": "root",
                    "password": "root",
                    "database": "monitor"
                }]
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there you can use [kafka manager](https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager) project. It will make to manage all kafka services in handy mode